# Fake EC2 endpoint for testing

Tags: testing, amazon-ec2, mocking, boto

Is there an open source package that implements a "fake Amazon EC2" endpoint out there? Specifically, one that can be used for testing against clients that talk to EC2 (in particular, using boto)?

I know there are several open source cloud solutions out there that implement the EC2 API (e.g., OpenStack, Eucalyptus, CloudStack), but I'm looking for something where I can quickly bring up a fake EC2 server and configure it with canned responses for testing purposes.

Comment: This isn't EC2-specific, and so isn't *exactly* an answer, but in Ruby, I'd solve this using [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) -- a tool that intercepts HTTP requests made from your application, allowing your test suite to return arbitrary responses. Python has [HTTPretty](http://falcao.it/HTTPretty/) which appears to operate in a similar fashion.

Comment: @willglynn I'm really looking for a standalone test app rather than doing the monkey-patching inside my app. Also, I was hoping to be able to leverage somebody else's re-implementation of the EC2 API, rather than having to start with just the spec.

Comment: With webmock/HTTPretty, you don't have to monkey-patch anything -- as far as your app is concerned, you're talking to the remote endpoint. All the hackery happens inside the upstream library, you just specify what requests should receive what responses. Ruby also has [VCR](http://www.rubyinside.com/vcr-a-recorder-for-all-your-tests-http-interactions-4169.html), which makes it easy to record and replay interactions with remote APIs in your test suite.

Comment: @LorinHochstein, I don't think such service exists. Use micro instances for your tests - it's cheap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to check out [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto).  It basically mocks boto itself using HTTPretty to mock  the HTTP layer. Its nicely done and seems really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus have run a community cloud for many years which is freely available at http://www.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus-cloud/community-cloud - it won't work if you're wanting to mock out different EC2 API responses (and one thing to note is that the Eucalyptus API doesn't follow the EC2 API completely, particularly in how they set different fields) - mocking out your calls to Boto seems like the best bet if you really want to test with real EC2 responses